# C++ How to insert a new element in a sorted vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm creating a score table with the scores being stored in a Vector. When a new score is added and it's bigger then a current score in the Vector, I want that score to be added (Which I've done) but then I want all the scores behind that score to basically move back to make room for the new score.

So basically what I'm saying is when a new element is added to the Vector, I want all the elements behind that new element to be pushed back basically but I can't figure out a way to do it.

I was wondering if anyone had an idea?

**EDIT:**
To make it a little more clearer of what I want. Imagine you have 10 different scores like this:

```
500 400 385 350 300 265 200 100 50 20
```

And I want to add a new score to this array which equals something like 425. So what I want to happen is have that new score of 425 be placed between score 1 and 2 and have score 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10 to be pushed back so score 2 now is score 3, score 3 is now score 4 and so on till we get to score 10 where the original score 10 which is 20 doesn't exist anymore and has been replaced by score 9 which is 50

Comment: Maybe `vector::push_back`

Comment: I would not push anything back, but instead add the new score at the back and read back to front if you want your scores in order high to low.

Comment: *I want all the scores behind that score* -- What does "scores behind that score" really mean?  And why aren't you simply using `std::vector`, which has a `push_back` function?

Comment: Did you mean push infront? (newest element is in first index)

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `vector::insert()` which let you insert element at a specific position of the vector.

Comment: So you want to [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the vector after the `push_back`? If so, just do that (or [stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)).

Comment: I've made a Edit to the post to hopefully make it more understandable

Comment: So, you want to maintain 10 values in descending order? I would just add it, sort the vector, then resize it to 10.

Comment: Push back (append) to the vector, then sort the vector (in descending order).

Comment: That's perfect, Thanks guys! :)

Comment: You should use a [`priority queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

Comment: I answered the question you asked... You should change the title to better reflect the actual question you were asking. Essentially "How to sort score elements upon inserting them" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the standard library's algorithms.

Assuming that scores is your vector of scores, and ns the new score you want to insert:

First, find the first element smaller than the new score:

```
auto pos = std::find_if(scores.begin(), scores.end(), [ns](auto s) {
    return s < ns;
});
```

And then insert the new element at this position (`vector.insert(it, elem)` inserts elem before it).

```
scores.insert(pos, ns);
```

If you insert every element this way from the beginning, your vector will always be sorted. You can capitalize on this invariant by using [std::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound), which will make for a faster look-up.

To remove the lowest score after insertion, just use `pop_back()`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle a situation like this is to think about the data structures you need. Which is basically a `Score` and some kind of `Score` table, here I went with the name `Scoreboard` the score board is going to handle the adding of scores, scores simply know about themselves and have abstractions for comparing themselves against one another. In this case I found that we only really needed to know if score A is less than score B in order to order them. So I've only added an `operator<`  but this is the same pattern you should use any time you encounter a similar situation to this.

```
  class Score {
  private:
    std::string initials;
    int score;
  public:
    Score(const std::string & initials, int score) : initials(initials), score(score)
    {}

    int getValue() { return score; }

    bool operator< (const Score & rhs) {
      return this.score < rhs.score;
    }
  };


class Scoreboard {
private:
  std::vector<Score> score;

public:
  Scoreboard() { /* if score chart found on disk, deserialize() */ }
  ~Scoreboard() { /* if scores changed, serialize() to disk */ }


  /* All the magic is in this addScore method, and the scores.at(n) < score
 line where we're using the operator< from Score as above stated, in order
 to determine if the n'th score in the list is less than the score to add.
 If the n'th score is less than the score to add, then insert the score to
 add in place of the n'th score */

  void addScore(const Score & score) {
    if( scores.size() < 10 ) {
      scores.push_back(score);
    } else if( scores.back() < score ) {
      for( int n=0; n<scores.size(); ++n ) {
        if( scores.at(n) < score ) {
          scores.insert( n, score );
          break;
        }
      }
      while( scores.size() > 10 ) {
        scores.pop_back();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't sort in descending order or cap the list at 10 items. Since you've got a sorted list you could do a binary search or use one of the algorithms that does that, but for 10 items linear is fine. I would add a check for the new items being less than the last item so you can ignore it without the search.

Comment: Don't rely on custom algorithms unless you really need to. <algorithm> gets them always right and generally better than you would. In that case `std::upper_bound` is a good candidate.

Comment: This does sort in descending order, recheck the logic. It starts from the beginning of the list, until it finds an element that is smaller than it, and when it finds one it inserts itself in front of that element. That's sorting from greatest to least, or in descending order.

Comment: I made edits for your other changes Retired Ninja, you're right I didn't cap the score, and also that adding a score shouldn't occur unless the score at least scored higher than the last item on the chart

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is an STL container that was developed precisely for such purposes. A priority queue takes care of the sorting and allows for the dynamic insertion of new elements with the `push` member function.

Here is how your problem could be solved:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> queue2vector(std::priority_queue<int>& q){  
  std::vector<int> v;
  while(!q.empty()) {
    v.push_back(q.top());
    q.pop();
  }
  return v;
}

int main() {
  std::priority_queue<int> q;
  // initialization (the scores are sorted upon insertion into the queue)
  std::vector<int> scores = {100, 50, 385, 350, 20, 200, 265, 500, 400, 300};  
  for(int n : scores)    
    q.push(n);
  // insert new element:
  q.push(425);
  // copy to std::vector:
  scores = queue2vector(q);
  // truncate vector to include only the first 10 entries:
  if(scores.size() > 10) scores.resize(10);     
  // output:
  for(int n : scores)
    std::cout << n << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

> 500 425 400 385 350 300 265 200 100 50